# Make callback of element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have button and I need to call it and take (show) an id (number) and after hide it.

I have got this line :

```
<div id="follow_21" class="button rounded" title="">Follow</div>
```

I do not know how to call (onclick) or other way this button and take only 21 and show it in alert('');

I tried `onclick="follow()`:

```
<div onclick="follow(21)" class="button rounded" title="">Follow</div>
```

and function :

```
function follow(event){
    alert(event);
}
```

alert works good but I don't know how to `hide()` element by clicking on it.
Suppose you will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery's hide function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
    <div id="follow_21" class="button rounded" title="" onclick="$(this).hide();">Folow</div>

    or preferably something like:

    <div id="follow_21" class="button rounded" title="">Folow</div>
    <script type="text/javascript>
        //Binds a click event to all divs that start with "follow_"
        $('div[id^="follow_"]').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            var idSplit = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
            alert('Follow - ' + idSplit);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: 21 is not static so here is problem calling it... here can be 1,32,12,43 that why I do not how to call it

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs I have made the solution more general. Is 1,32,12,43 a piece of data that you're using or is it only used for the id?

Comment: thank you ! This code is good can you please tell how to call ID - 21 in alert? so when I click it shows me 21 and after hide. Hide workds nice but interesting how to catch id?

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs Updated to alert id.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path:

```
<div id="follow_21" onclick="follow(21)" class="button rounded" title="">Follow</div>

function follow(id){
    document.getElementById('follow_' + id).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Or even easier:

```
<div onclick="follow(this);" class="button rounded" title="">Follow</div>

function follow(div){
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

With jquery and the .click()

```
<div id="follow_21" class="button rounded" title="">Follow</div>

$('#follow_21').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: thank you ! Can you show please how to call it from .click(function () if of course it is possible.

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs There u go ^ :)

Comment: 21 is user id and it can change so how to call id if it name will changes as I see only onclick="follow(21) ? or it is possible to do and call .click(function() if last part of id will not be static

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs I think you're trying to approach this the wrong way. If all this is being generated by a PHP script of some sort, then why not let PHP echo the user ids as JSON so it can be used by javascript to iterate through. If you want I can show you an example of that.

Comment: Sorry do not see you answer! Cna you please give an example . here I post my full working code but still think that it is not good to use so many elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149833/need-advice-how-to-get-id-data-jquery

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs I'm sorry, at the time of writing that comment I had a pretty good idea of what you could try as well using JSON. But I can't seem to think of it anymore. The way you have it now is good.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `onclick` attribute, `this` means "this element".  So you can pass `this` to your function:

HTML:

```
<div id="follow_21" onclick="follow(this)" class="button rounded" title="">Follow</div>
```

JS:

```
function follow(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

With that said, you can get your JS out of your HTML. This is considered a Very Good Thing. This is very easy with jQuery, and you can remove the `onclick` attribute entirely:

```
$('#follow_21').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: $('#follow_21').click(function()  problem is that 21 is an user id and it will change so here is a problem call only by part of id ? is it possible ?

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs Yes, `$('div[id^="follow_']")`. Ideally, however, select it by some other means. For instance, by a class unique to the element, or by its parent element. If, for instance, it's the only `div` in an element with the ID `userinfo`, `$('#userinfo div').click...` would work.